# jquery UI banner background image behind Tabs

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I am implementing jQuery tabs in a ruby on rails application wherein I would like to have a banner be the background image behind the tabs ***in the navigation bar***. For example, in the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/cjU7D/), The picture of the cat would be in the grey area ***behind*** the 'About' tab.

Currently, the height of the tabs appears to readjust to fit the banner, however it is not displayed and the default gray area of the navigation bar is only shown.

here is the code in my _tab.html.erb:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
 <script>
 $(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs({

    });
      });
</script>
```

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<%= render "shared/tab"%> 
</head>

<body>

<div id="tabs">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">About</a></li>  
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
<%= render "shared/about"%>
  </div>
```

i've tried adding

```
#tabs{ background-image: url(images/banner2.jpg); }
```

to the css file, but this did not work. I apologize if this is a simple question, but any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!!!

Comment: What's different between http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/cjU7D/ and what you're doing? Are you sure that `images/banner2.jpg` is the right path?

Comment: I'd like the image behind the tabs, i.e the navigation bar area be the banner rather than inside the tab pane. I'm not sure if the url is correct, since I'm using Ror I'm just using the default path, app>assets>images/banner2.jpg. I'm assuming the path is right, since the navigation bar does adjust it's height to match that of the banner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the image as a background for the tab-bar then you'd want to work with the `<ul>` rather than the whole `<div>`, something like this:

```
#tabs > ul {
    background-image: url(/assets/banner2.jpg)
}
```

I switched the URL to `/assets/banner2.jpg` since that's where the server would usually find the image. You could also use the [`image_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_path) helper if you have a lot of these things and don't mind ERBifying your CSS a little bit.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/cjU7D/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just make it the background for the UL, instead of the tabs div.

```
#tabs ul {
     background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/500/100);
}
```